# Is it possible to use find along with stderr

Tags: linux, shell

I am facing an issue with STDERR,I hope I am missing something.
Please look at the below syntax and output.

```
find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec cat {} + | grep kali 2> /dev/null
```

Output:

```
cat: /etc/sudoers.d/README: Permission denied
cat: /etc/sudoers.d/kali-grant-root: Permission denied
cat: /etc/sudoers.d/ospd-openvas: Permission denied
cat: /etc/sudoers.d/live: Permission denied
```

So as per my understanding, the find is looking for a file type in "/etc/sudoers" and the output is executed using the cat command which is further grepped, so finally I will get a permission denied error because I am not a root user but 2> /dev/null should ignore the stedrr, Am I right/?

Comment: Note that you don't need a pipeline at all: `find` can execute `grep` for you. `find ... -exec grep kali {} +`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`2>/dev/null` only applies to a single command, not the full pipeline. In your case, only stderr of `grep` is redirected, but not stderr of `find`.

Either redirect each command or use a command group:

```
find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec cat {} + 2> /dev/null | grep kali 2> /dev/null
{ find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec cat {} + | grep kali; } 2> /dev/null
```

It is also possible to use a a subshell:

```
(find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec cat {} + | grep kali) 2> /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

It's `find` that produces the output you see, not `grep`. Where possible, eliminate the *source* of the error instead of ignoring *all* error output via redirection. In this case, you only want to call `cat` on the files you have permission to read.

```
find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec test -r \; -exec cat {} + | grep kali
```

Note that you don't need a pipe at all; let `find` execute `grep` for you.

```
find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec test -r \; -004 -exec grep kali {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouping all together:

```
{ find /etc/sudoers.d -type f -exec cat {} + | grep kali; }  2>/dev/null
```